# Counting the number of polygons containing origin in 2D

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, counting

Suppose we have n points in 2D space in convex position. There are precisely choose(n, k) different convex k-gons (non-degenerate). Is there any existing algorithm that runs in O(n log n) time (for a fixed k) which counts the number of polygons containing the origin?

I tried to look for any such algorithms in the literature, but only managed to find an algorithm for k=3.

Comment: We can build many distinct k-gons from k points. What ones you are going to take into consideration?

Comment: Only the non-degenerate ones.  Also we can assume that the points are in general position. Basically, the task is to find how many of the choose(n,k) k-gons contain the origin. The naive approach would take O(n^k).

Comment: "There are precisely choose(n, k) different k-gons" Really?

Comment: Well if we consider only non-degenerate ones, and also that points are in general position, then yes. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Say we have 5 points (0,0.5), (1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1). To my reckoning there are at least 4 5-gons and at least 9 4-gons (but I'm counting in my head so I can miss something).

Comment: Ohhh, thank you. I forgot to add that I only consider convex polygons. I am sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: Then there are 0 convex 5-gons and 3 convex 4-gons. Now if all your points lie on their convex hull, you indeed have choose (n,k) k-gons.

Comment: What's the algorithm for k-3? Interested to learn how is O(n log n), since C(n,3) itself is way larger than that.

Comment: This : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001909090217L or this https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X92906583

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sweep line algorithm.

First, count up polygons. Then sweep a line around, removing polygons not containing the origin when the polygon is fully in view, then has its first point removed.

```
import math

def choose (n, m):
    # Special case this to avoid division by zero.
    if n < m:
        return 0
    else:
        answer = 1
        for i in range(m):
            answer = (answer * (n-i)) // (i+1)
        return answer



# I assume that points are (x, y) pairs here.
def count_poly_containing_origin (k, points):
    # Start with total number of polygons, subtract those without origin.
    polys = choose(len(points), k)

    # Convert ones not at origin to angle with -pi < angle <= pi
    angles = []
    for x, y in points:
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            pass # I'm assuming closed polygons. Have this, have origin.
        else:
            angles.append(math.atan2(x, y))

    angles = sorted(angles)

    # We are going to sweep a line around. We will add each point when we
    # see it, and remove it math.pi later. When we remove the point, we
    # subtract off how many polygons it is in that do not contain the origin.
    #
    #
    # i represents what we will remove next. j represents what we will add
    # next, selected is how many points are currently selected.
    #
    # We start nothing selected, added, or removed.

    i = j = selected = 0
    while i < len(angles):
        if i <= j:
            if angles[j] < angles[i] + math.pi:
                # add point
                selected += 1
                j += 1
                # Do we need to wraparound?
                if j == len(angles):
                    j = 0
            else:
                # remove point
                selected -= 1
                i += 1
                # Remove the polygons containing angles[i] and not the origin.
                polys -= choose(selected, k-1)
        else:
            if angles[j] < angles[i] - math.pi:
                # add point
                selected += 1
                j += 1
            else:
                # remove point
                selected -= 1
                i += 1
                # Remove the polygons containing removed point and not the origin.
                polys -= choose(selected, k-1)
 
    return polys
```

For fixed `k` this is a `O(n log(n))` algorithm. For large `k` the bottleneck is repeatedly calculating `choose(m, k-1)` for the subtraction. That can be sped up by creating a lookup table for it in `O(n)`. (Left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a nice one.  Is that something one just comes up with or is it taken from somewhere?

Comment: @Neremintos Just comes up with. But out of pieces that you get from seeing other problems. I certainly didn't just invent the idea of a line sweeping around.

Comment: @Neremintos I actually came up with a very similar idea. There are lots of similar problems around.